# Why does Java's ConcurrentSkipListMap's Iterator greedily cache the next item?

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator, java.util.concurrent, concurrentskiplistmap

I was looking over Java's ConcurrentSkipListMap, because it's an fascinating data structure and seem applicable to my use, but the iterator has some interesting behavior that seems counterintuitive to me. Take for example the following code:

```
Map<String, Integer> ages = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
ages.put("Bob", 28);
Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = ages.entrySet().iterator();

System.out.println("HasBob? " + iterator.hasNext());
iterator.next();

ages.put("Jon", 25);
System.out.println("HasJon? " + iterator.hasNext());
```

The idea is that the map is initialized with values, create an iterator, and starts iterating. In between these operations, another thread puts 'Jon' in the map. For simplicity's sake, instead of using actual threads and loops in my example, I just put the code in the contrived order, and directly reference each item.

I expected the output to be `true/true`, but the actual output is `true/false`. Digging into the Map's implementation, I found the iterator caches the next Node/Value (in its advance() method). This cache will skip any next items created right after iterator.next() is called. Why does it greedily cache the next item instead of waiting until the Iterator next() method is called before advancing the next item?

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, the iterator makes no guarantees about whether it reflects modifications to the Map made after the iterator's construction. There's no reason to expect the second `hasNext` to return `true`.

Comment: You have two options: remain on the current, even after next() has been called and maintain a "used" flag, or advance and cache the successor of the element. If you do the former, what would you do if remove() is called? You have to return the resources of the current element, sort of sawing off the branch on which you are sitting.

Comment: @laune Could you explain to me the difference between the two? If remove is called, then the item and node are removed from the structure, but wouldn't it still point to the next node and could be used to advance?

Comment: Holding on to a removed element in a collection across all implementation techniques isn't something to be taken lightly. All sort s of invariants may not be true any more. I admit, I've not thought this through, but based on general principles I'd say that it is the reason for the choice that's been made in this implementation.